# Use proxy to get Azure key vault secrets

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-devops, proxy, azure-keyvault

I have a C# ASP.NET project that retrieves certain secrets from Azure Key Vault using two libraries, Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets and Azure.Identity. How can I make the GetSecretAsync request go through a proxy? I need to set up a proxy specifically for these calls. Is there a recommended way to achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Azure.Core.Pipeline;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;


namespace Helpers
{
    public class KeyVaultHelper
    {
        public static Settings Get()
        {
            try
            {
                string keyVaultUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
                string proxyAddress = "http://myproxy.bankfab.com:8080";

                var appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_ID"];
                var appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_KEY"];
                var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TENANT_ID"];

                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, appId, appKey);

                var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

                var publicKey = secretClient.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret1"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;
                var secretKey = secretClient.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret2"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;
                var clientId = secretClient.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret3"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;
                var clientSecret = secretClient.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret4"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;

                return new Settings 
                {
                    Secret1 = publicKey.Value,
                    Secret2 = secretKey.Value,
                    Secret3 = clientId.Value,
                    Secret4 = clientSecret.Value
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create a new http with a proxy, and try to use it, but I have no idea if its correct.

```
string proxyAddress = "http://your-proxy-address";
var proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = proxy,
        UseProxy = true,
    };
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
 var secretClientOptions = new SecretClientOptions
                    {
                        Transport = new HttpClientTransport(httpClient)
                    };

var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential, secretClientOptions);

    //my logic with GetSecretAsync
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you followed is indeed correct. I also tested it and successfully retrieved Azure Key Vault secrets using a proxy with the below code.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

class Program
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Configure a named HttpClient with proxy settings
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxx"),
            UseProxy = true,
        }))
        {
            // Create a new instance of the SecretClient class
            SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://proxy3.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());


            // Use the SecretClient to retrieve secrets
            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret("PublicKeySecretName");

            // Now you can use the retrieved secret
            Console.WriteLine($"Secret: {secret.Value}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Secret Saved in portal**
[image]

**Got Values in Console and debugging**
[image]

[image]